# constructing a matrix such its square is not '0' but its cube is.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-equations

i have been asked to construct a matrix A such that $A^2$ is not equal to '0' but, $A^3=0$. how should i proceed.

i can only understand that all the eigenvalues for A , $A^2$ and $A^3$ will be 'zero' but then how to proceed !

please don't give me the answer only. i want to know how to proceed !

I TRIED CAYLEY HAMILTON THEOREM . (if $\lambda $ is the eigenvalue of A)

if $A^3=0  =>(\lambda)^3 =0  => (\lambda)=0 =>(\lambda)^2=0 =>A^2=0   $
so this is not possible . is there any fallacy in my application cayley hamilton. please point me out.

Comment: The implication in the Cayley-Hamilton goes only so far - it tells us that the matrix satisfies its own characteristic equation. But it doesn't go further and tell us that the matrix satisfies every polynomial equation satisfied by its eigenvalues.

Comment: $A3=0=>(λ)^3=0=>(λ)=0=>(λ)^2=0$ . you mean , upto this is right ? then A^2=0 is not right ! right ?

Comment: I think that's it.

Answer (score 3):

First the minimal polynomial of the matrix is $x^3$, hence the matrix has dimension $\ge3$.

With the Jordan canonical form, you can have this:
$$A=\begin{bmatrix}0&1&0\\0&0&1\\0&0&0\end{bmatrix},\quad A^2=\begin{bmatrix}0&0&1\\0&0&0\\0&0&0\end{bmatrix},\quad A^3=0.$$
Any matrix that is similar to $A$ will have the same property.

Comment: thanks but , 


I TRIED CALEY HAMILTON THEOREM . (if $\lambda $ is the eigenvalue of A)


if $A^3=0  =>(\lambda)^3 =0  => (\lambda)=0 =>(\lambda)^2=0 =>A^2=0   $
so what mistake did i do ?

Comment: You confused eigenvalue ($\lambda$, $0$ here) andcharacteristic  polynomial which has eigenvalues as roots ($x^3$). Indeed, in the real numbers, $\lambda^3=0\Rightarrow \lambda=0$. But in the ring of $3\times 3$ matrices, this is no more true: a matrix can have a power equal to 0, without being $0$ (such a matrix is called a *nilpotent* matrix). This ring also has *zero-divisors* ($AB=0$ with $A,B\ne 0$), which is very different from what happens with real or complex numbers.